# $p \in \mathbb{R}$ so that $\mu(\{n\}):=n^p(-1)^n, n \in \mathbb{N}$ is a signed measure

Tags: measure-theory

$(\Omega,\mathcal{A)=(\mathbb{N}, \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N}))}$

$\mu(\{n\}):=n^p(-1)^n, n \in \mathbb{N}$

For which $p \in \mathbb{R}$ is $\mu$ a signed measure?

I know the definition of signed measure but unfortunately I'm not able to do this task.

Comment: I believe it's like this, but someone should correct me. $\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^p= |\mu|(\mathbb{N}) < \infty \implies p<-1$

Comment: @reuns I see my mistake now. I wasn't aware that it can attain infinite values. $\mu_+(\mathbb{N}) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty (2n)^p<\infty \,\lor \mu_-(\mathbb{N}) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty (2n-1)^p<\infty \implies p<-1$. Is that right?

Comment: @Jakobian Well forget it, the definitions suggest you are right but you need to give an argument for it (I thought difference of non-negative measures always was a signed measure, but it is not, because we require the series in the countable additivity to be well-defined independently of the ordering, so $\sum_n n = +\infty$ but $\sum_n (-1)^n n$ is undefined)

Comment: @Jakobian So is the solution $p<-1$? Can you please explain a bit how you came to that conclusion? Thanks!

Comment: Nevermind I think I understood it now